# Not Converging CTC Loss and Fluctuating Label Error Rate (Edit Distance) on Single Example?

Tags: python, tensorflow, handwriting-recognition

I am trying to overfit a handwriting recognition model of this architecture:

```
features = slim.conv2d(features, 16, [3, 3])
features = slim.max_pool2d(features, 2)
features = mdrnn(features, 16)
features = slim.conv2d(features, 32, [3, 3])
features = slim.max_pool2d(features, 2)
features = mdrnn(features, 32)
features = slim.conv2d(features, 64, [3, 3])
features = slim.max_pool2d(features, 2)
features = mdrnn(features, 64)
features = slim.conv2d(features, 128, [3, 3])
features = mdrnn(features, 128)
features = slim.max_pool2d(features, 2)
features = slim.conv2d(features, 256, [3, 3])
features = slim.max_pool2d(features, 2)
features = mdrnn(features, 256)
features = _reshape_to_rnn_dims(features)
features = bidirectional_rnn(features, 128)
features = bidirectional_rnn(features, 128)
features = bidirectional_rnn(features, 128)
features = bidirectional_rnn(features, 128)
features = bidirectional_rnn(features, 128)
```

With this mdrnn code from tensorflow (with a few modifications):

```
def mdrnn(inputs, num_hidden):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, "multidimensional_rnn", [inputs]):
        hidden_sequence_horizontal = _bidirectional_rnn_scan(inputs,
                                                             num_hidden // 2)
        with tf.variable_scope("vertical"):
            transposed = tf.transpose(hidden_sequence_horizontal, [0, 2, 1, 3])
            output_transposed = _bidirectional_rnn_scan(transposed, num_hidden // 2)
        output = tf.transpose(output_transposed, [0, 2, 1, 3])
        return output

def _bidirectional_rnn_scan(inputs, num_hidden):
    with tf.variable_scope("BidirectionalRNN", [inputs]):
        height = inputs.get_shape().as_list()[1]
        inputs = images_to_sequence(inputs)
        output_sequence = bidirectional_rnn(inputs, num_hidden)
        output = sequence_to_images(output_sequence, height)
        return output

def images_to_sequence(inputs):
    _, _, width, num_channels = _get_shape_as_list(inputs)
    s = tf.shape(inputs)
    batch_size, height = s[0], s[1]
    return tf.reshape(inputs, [batch_size * height, width, num_channels])

def sequence_to_images(tensor, height):
    num_batches, width, depth = tensor.get_shape().as_list()
    if num_batches is None:
        num_batches = -1
    else:
        num_batches = num_batches // height
    reshaped = tf.reshape(tensor,
                          [num_batches, width, height, depth])
    return tf.transpose(reshaped, [0, 2, 1, 3])

def bidirectional_rnn(inputs, num_hidden, concat_output=True,
                      scope=None):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, "bidirectional_rnn", [inputs]):
        cell_fw = rnn.LSTMCell(num_hidden)
        cell_bw = rnn.LSTMCell(num_hidden)
        outputs, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw,
                                                     cell_bw,
                                                     inputs,
                                                     dtype=tf.float32)
        if concat_output:
            return tf.concat(outputs, 2)
        return outputs
```

The training ctc_loss decreases but it doesn't converge even after a thousand epochs. The label error rate just fluctuates.

[image]

I preprocess the image such that it looks like this:

[image]

I also noticed that the network generates the same predictions at some points:

```
INFO:tensorflow:outputs = [[51 42 70 42 34 42 34 42 34 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29
  42 29  4 72 42 58 20]] (1.156 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:labels = [[38 78 52 29 70 51 78  8  1 78 15  8  1 22 78 52  4 24 78 28  3  9  8 15
  11 14 13 13 78  2  4  1 16]] (1.156 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:label_error_rate = 0.93939394 (1.156 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0.888003
INFO:tensorflow:outputs = [[51 42 70 42 34 42 34 42 34 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29
  42 29  4 65 42 58 20]] (1.126 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:labels = [[38 78 52 29 70 51 78  8  1 78 15  8  1 22 78 52  4 24 78 28  3  9  8 15
  11 14 13 13 78  2  4  1 16]] (1.126 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:label_error_rate = 0.969697 (1.126 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0.866796
INFO:tensorflow:outputs = [[51 42 70 42 34 42 34 42 34 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29
  42 29  4 65 42 58 20]] (1.154 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:labels = [[38 78 52 29 70 51 78  8  1 78 15  8  1 22 78 52  4 24 78 28  3  9  8 15
  11 14 13 13 78  2  4  1 16]] (1.154 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:label_error_rate = 0.969697 (1.154 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0.88832
INFO:tensorflow:outputs = [[51 42 70 42 34 42 34 42 34 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29 42 29
  42 29  4 65 42 58 20]] (1.126 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:labels = [[38 78 52 29 70 51 78  8  1 78 15  8  1 22 78 52  4 24 78 28  3  9  8 15
  11 14 13 13 78  2  4  1 16]] (1.126 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:label_error_rate = 0.969697 (1.126 sec)
```

Any reason why this is happening? Here's a small reproducible example I've made https://github.com/selcouthlyBlue/CNN-LSTM-CTC-HIGH-LOSS

**Update**

When I changed the conversion from this:

```
outputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1, num_outputs])
logits = slim.fully_connected(outputs, num_classes)
logits = tf.reshape(logits, [num_steps, -1, num_classes])
```

To this:

```
outputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1, num_outputs])
logits = slim.fully_connected(outputs, num_classes)
logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, num_steps, num_classes])
logits = tf.transpose(logits, (1, 0, 2))
```

The performance somehow improved:

(Removed the mdrnn layers here)

[image]

(2nd RUN)

[image]

(Added back the mdrnn layers)

[image]

But the loss is still not going down to zero (or getting close to it), and the label error rate is still fluctuting.

After changing the optimizer from `Adam` to `RMSProp` with decay rate of `0.9`, the loss now converges!

[image: rms prop improvement 1]

[image: rms prop improvement 2]

But the label error rate still fluctuates. However, it should go down now with the loss converging.

**More updates**

I tried it on the real dataset I have, and it did improve!

Before

[image: before progress]

After

[image: improved training progress]

But the label error rate is increasing for some reason still unknown.

Comment: I've no time to debug this at the moment, but after looking at your code I would recommend to check your usage of the reshape function (e.g. when mapping CNN output to RNN or RNN to CTC). If you just want to change axis (e.g. TxBxC -> BxTxC), you should use transpose. reshape may scramble the data in a way one would not expect at first sight.

Comment: I checked my code, and I think I'm doing what you said. From cnn, I transpose the outputs to `nwhc` format then I reshape it to `[n, w, h * c]` to match the shape required by RNN `[B, T, C]` (`[T, B, C]` if `time_major=True`). For mapping RNN output to CTC, I reshape the inputs first to `[-1, number_of_hidden_layers_in_last_rnn_layer]`, then pass it to a fully connected layer with `num_classes` number units, then reshape it to `[w, n, num_classes]` to pass it to CTC.

Comment: I changed  the way I map RNN to CTC outputs. I updated the post with the code.

Comment: When I changed the optimizer, the performance suddenly improved! Check the post for updates.